# How to fetch/ get all the arguments of the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

With JavaScript we have arguments property that lets us get the arguments of the function. I generally do it this way

```
function sum(){
    var agumentCount = arguments.length;
    var count =0;
    var sumArguments = [];

    // Fetching the arguments
    while(count != agumentCount){
        sumArguments.push(arguments[count]);
        count++;
    }

    // function logic -- neglect this
    var data = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<sumArguments.length;i++){
        data+=sumArguments[i];
    }
    return data;
}
```

// Calling the function

```
sum(2,3);
sum(9,15,65,458748);
sum();
sum(1);
```

Is there better way of fetching the arguments, as this takes O(n), where n is the number of arguments for the function.

Comment: pass them in a single argument as array

Comment: You can merge two loops: 1. fetching argument 2. Run the for loop for each argument

Comment: @SandeshGupta I am doing the same thing know, but I need a better way of fetching the arguments.

Comment: How are you expecting to make it more efficient? You'll have to read the argument atleast once to perform any operation on it (thereby making it O(n))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code it will not reduce complexity but it's much better approach to this kind of operation -

```
function sum() {
  var arr = Array.from(arguments);

  return arr.reduce(function(total, x) {
    return total + x;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `...`, the spread operator to work with variable number of arguments:

```
function sum(...nums){ //The arguments are stored in the nums array.
    var sum = 0;
    nums.forEach(function(num){
        sum+=num;
    });
    return sum;
}

sum(1,2,3,4,5,6); //21
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) out for more information.

EDIT:

Use the `reduce` function for more concise and readable code:

```
function sum(...nums){
    return nums.reduce(function(add,num){
        return add+num;
    });
}
sum(1,2,3,4,5,6);  //21
```

Comment: The reduce logic works when there are arugments, but when the arguments are empty it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to fetch the arguments.
You can check if the first argument is an array and loop through that array.

```js
function sum() {
  let array= [],
    ans = 0;
    
  // Array check.
  if (arguments[0] instanceof Array)
    array = arguments[0];
  else array = arguments;
  
  // Sum all from array
  const max = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    ans += array[i];
  }
  
  return ans;
}

console.log(sum(1,2,3));
console.log(sum([4,5,6]));
console.log(sum());
console.log(sum(7,8));
```

Answer (score 0):

arguments is like array because

1.it return item by index;

2.it has length property.

**but actually it is not an array** because it is not generated by constructor Array, therefor it doesn't inheritance the prototype functions of Array.

This is a defect for the design of JavaScript.

Lucky you can still "borrow" the prototype functions of Array to generate an actual array.

```
function a(){ 
 var arr=Array.prototype.concat.apply(arguments);
}
```